# Updating Bucket List With Dynamic UI in Shiny (with reproducible sample)

Tags: r, shiny

I am in the process of building a shiny app in which I am wanting to use a bucket list. I want to use that bucket list to be dynamic in that the options for the bucket list are only the plants for the selected division from a previous menu option. So in other words, when a division is selected, the options on the bucket list will change to only those plants at a particular division.

Below is a sample shiny app for this project. Essentially all that I want is for the labels on the first rank list to be dynamic and change when the user filters the division. I have done some research but am completely stuck here. My guess is it's not all that difficult to do, but I am stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(sortable)

#dataframe for this sample:
data<- data.frame(division = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
               plant = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "x", "m", "p", "c", "x", "a", "b"),
               value = c(12,15,23,15,14,64,63,12,4, 18, 31, 1))

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(
 dashboardHeader(title = "Test App"),
 dashboardSidebar(
     sidebarMenu(
         menuItem("Data", tabName = "data"),
         menuItem("Drag and Drop", tabName = "drag")
     )
 ),
 dashboardBody(
     sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                  selectInput("division", "Select Division:", choices = c("all", 1,2,3))
                  
                  ),
               
     tabItems(
         tabItem(tabName = "data",
              box(title = "Data", width = 9, status = "primary", height = "auto",
                 solidHeader = T, dataTableOutput("preview1"))
             ),
         tabItem(tabName = "drag",
             bucket_list(
                 header = "Interactive bucket list",
                 group_name = "bucket_list_group",
                 orientation = "horizontal",
                 add_rank_list(text = "Bucket 1",
                               labels = c("a", "b", "c"), input_id = "default"),
                 add_rank_list(text = "bucket 2",
                               labels = NULL,
                               input_id = "bucket2")
                 )
             )
     )
 )
     
)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
 filtered<- reactive({
     if(input$division == "all"){
         data
     } else{
         data %>% filter(division == input$division)
     }
 })
 output$preview1<-renderDataTable(
     datatable(filtered(), options = list(searching = T, pageLength =10, scrollX = T))
 )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right then your desired result could be achieved via `uiOutput` and `renderUI` like so:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(sortable)

#dataframe for this sample:
data<- data.frame(division = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                  plant = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "x", "m", "p", "c", "x", "a", "b"),
                  value = c(12,15,23,15,14,64,63,12,4, 18, 31, 1))

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test App"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Data", tabName = "data"),
      menuItem("Drag and Drop", tabName = "drag")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                 selectInput("division", "Select Division:", choices = c("all", 1,2,3))
                 
    ),
    
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "data",
              box(title = "Data", width = 9, status = "primary", height = "auto",
                  solidHeader = T, dataTableOutput("preview1"))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "drag",
              uiOutput("bucket")
      )
    )
  )
  
)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  filtered<- reactive({
    if(input$division == "all"){
      data
    } else{
      data %>% filter(division == input$division)
    }
  })
  
  output$bucket <- renderUI({
    bucket_list(
      header = "Interactive bucket list",
      group_name = "bucket_list_group",
      orientation = "horizontal",
      add_rank_list(text = "Bucket 1",
                    labels = unique(filtered()$plant), input_id = "default"),
      add_rank_list(text = "bucket 2",
                    labels = NULL,
                    input_id = "bucket2")
    )  
  })
  
  output$preview1<-renderDataTable(
    datatable(filtered(), options = list(searching = T, pageLength =10, scrollX = T))
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That works perfectly! I didn't think this would be a hard question. I thought the renderUI command might be a way to do it, I just wasn't sure how to actually implement. This is a lot of help. Thank you!